# How to show all x-axis tick values

Tags: node.js, plotly, scatter-plot, plotly-python, xticks

I am using this library

https://plot.ly/nodejs/axes/

**to plot graphs in node.js. I have this code:**

```
var data = [
  {
    x: xs,
    y: ys,
    type: "scatter"
  }
];

var graphOptions = {filename: "date-axes", fileopt: "overwrite"};
plotly.plot(data, graphOptions, function (err, msg) {
    console.log(msg);
    console.log("DONE!");
});
```

to plot a graph with 5000 x-axis points. The problem is that in the rendered image, it x-axis values are not continuously increment by for each value I put. There is a rather large step, for example, if the x-axis labels are

```
['item1', 'item2', ..., 'item5000']
```

then it outputs with labels

`['item1', 'item10', ..., 'item5000']`

All the yaxis points are there, but I just want to see all `x-axis` labels.

Does anyone know what setting enables this? I assume that they did this by default so the text labels don't overlap each other, but in my case I want to see them all.

Thanks

Comment: fig.update_xaxes(tickangle=-45, showticklabels = True, type = 'category')

Answer (score 43):

I am using Python, though I have encountered the same problem. When you are specifying the layout of your chart, you need to set `tickmode='linear'`, at least it worked for me!

```
import plotly 
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

layout = go.Layout(
    title='some title',
    xaxis=dict(
        title='Xaxis Name',
        tickmode='linear')
```

Comment: In python, this also works : `fig.update_xaxes(tickmode='linear')`

Comment: Works also in R

Answer (score 12):

Use `layout.xaxis.dtick`

Example here: https://plot.ly/nodejs/axes/

Comment: Thats the right answer. Just setting `dtick:1`, showed all tick labels.

Comment: `dtick=1` in Python Plotly did not work for me.  In fact, it removed all but one x axis tick from my graph in Aug 2022.

Comment: @devdanke odd, dtick=1 worked for me in Python.

Answer (score 7):

I run into the same problem and I managed to solve it: the trick is to define your values on xaxis as "categorical". 
This is what my code looked like:

```js
var layout = {
        xaxis: {
            tickangle: 35,
            showticklabels: true,
            type: 'category',
        }
    };
    Plotly.newPlot(divname, data, layout);
```